# Solutions of diophantine equation: $s^2 = (ad)^2+ (bc-ad+4ac)^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Given diophantine equation:

$$s^2 = (ad)^2 + (bc-ad+4ac)^2$$

$s,a,b,c,d$ are all variables. They are all odd.

a and b are coprime. c and d are coprime.

How do you parametrize all the solutions? Are there any methods to do so? Appreciate any tips to analyzing the solutions to this. Thanks.

EDIT: Interesting property (at least at first glance to me). If I run for solutions on a computer... and I set $a,b,c,d$ all $\ge n$ for some n, the frequency of solutions drops fast as I increase n. If I set n to 199, I get no solutions checking all variables up to 1000. What's the reason for this?

Comment: Is $s$ fixed? ${}$

Comment: No. s is a variable.

Comment: May I ask where this has come from? It seems too ugly to appear out of nowhere.

Comment: Well, I was working on a problem regarding rational distances and pythagorean triples. I eventually got to this equation.

Comment: Can you state that problem too in your question?

Comment: $$ad=2pt$$ $$a=t$$ $$d=2p$$ $$bc-2pt+4tc=p^2-t^2$$  It remains to solve the last equation.